# Specify special folder in mongodb config

Tags: mongodb, configuration, yaml

I would like to specify `ProgramData` folder in my MongoDB configuration file

```
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
   dbPath: "%programdata%/db/"
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
```

Does anyone know the way to achieve this as `%programdata%` substitution doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any possible confusion or problem, I would recommend to hardcode the real path like so :

```
    storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
   dbPath: "c:\ProgramData\db"
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
```

If this is not for a production system, that should do it.
On the other hand, if it is for a production system I would recommend a Linux.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/#supported-production